For each unique email found load all correlating attachments
I am trying to automatically create emails that include all associated attachments with the email. I have an excel document that is being referenced for the emails and attachments.
index = 0
counter = 0
for email in emails:
    mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    mailItem.Subject = 
    mailItem.BodyFormat = 1
    mailItem.Body = 
    mailItem.To = email
    counter = counter + 1

    for attachment in attachments:
        mailItem.Attachments.Add(attachment)
    index+=1
    mailItem.Display()

counter+=1





emails
attachments




email 1
attach A


email 1
attach B


email 2
attach C


email 3
attach D



I thought that a while or if statement might be the answer but I can't seem to get it to work. I know that the code listed above will provide me four emails but it includes all attachments when it cycles through each of the email addresses. What I would like it to do is provide three email addresses with the first only including attach A and B. Email 2 only including attach C and Email 3 only including attach D.

Why does email 1 get 2 attachments, but email 2 and email 3 only get 1 attachment each? How do you know which attachments are for each email?

@barmar email 1 is referencing a unique email and since it is listed twice in the excel table, both attach A and B would be assigned to this email. Email 2 is the next unique email and attach C is the attachment in line with this. If email 1 was listed all 4 times, then all the attachments (A,B,C,D) would be applied to this email.

Use zip() to loop over them in parallel: for email, attachment in zip(emails, attachments):

@Barmar unless I'm misunderstanding, this almost works. It is associating the correct email to attach, but it is still producing 4 emails instead of 3 emails when I use zip().

Isn't that what you want? I see 4 rows in your desired table.

It sounds like what you need to do is create a dictionary whose keys are the emails, and values are the list of attachments. Then when you're looping, you can append the attachment to the dictionary for that email, and it will group them together. Then you can loop over the dictionary and create the emails.

@Barmar I apologize for the confusion. I only want one email sent per unique email address(email 1) but if the email is listed multiple times, that is only used to group all the attachments that are associated with that email. If email 1 was repeated 13 times, there would only be one email to email 1 and it would include 13 attachments.

Create a dictionary that maps each email to a list of attachments. Then when you have multiple attachments for an email, you can append them all to the same message instead of creating a new message.
from collections import defaultdict

attach_dict = {}
for email, attachment in zip(emails, attachments):
    attach_dict.setdefault(email, []).append(attachment)

for email, atts in attach_dict.items():
    mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    mailItem.Subject = "subject"
    mailItem.BodyFormat = 1
    mailItem.Body = "message body"
    mailItem.To = email

    for attachment in atts:
        mailItem.Attachments.Add(attachment)
    mailItem.Display()

counter = len(attach_dict)


This is exactly what I was hoping to accomplish, thank you!!!
